# C SDK for Cloudant?

Tags: c, ibm-cloud, cloudant

When I went through the supported client libraries for Cloudant as offered by IBM Cloud, the available supported libraries are Mobile, Java, Python, Node.js, Swift.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/libraries/supported.html#supported-client-libraries

I wanted to enquire if they offer support for C language because I want to integrate Cloudant on IBM Cloud with my Linux host?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Cloudant is one of the databases offered by IBM Cloud. Your Linux host has support for many programming languages. You can even access Cloudant using http, without any SDK (language library). What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to develop a C sdk which can be integrated with any platform for analytics purpose. I have a Android, iOS SDK for real-time, on-device visual analytics ,  wanted to extend it for C platform

Answer (score 4):

You don’t need to use a client library, Cloudant has an easy to use REST API that you can interact with directly from your programming language of choice. To call the REST API from c you may want to use a generic REST library like libcurl.

Here are some resources for libcurl:

- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/
- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html
- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-easy.html
- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Here are the cloudant REST API docs:

- https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/index.html